# Getting cookies with google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I need to get weekly the cookies of all my team from their browsers. I use these cookies to scrape data from the internet. I need only 1 cookie related to 1 website.

I imagined this workflow:

1. They install a chrome extension on their browser
2. This chrome extension get the cookie every monday at 10am
3. This extension send the data to a google sheet

I have no idea how to create a google extension and don't even know if it's possible to create this kind of workflow. I have only knowledge on python.

Is it complicated to do that? What are the best way to build this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where are the cookies from? Such as what site etc. They may have an easier method to do the same thing.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? What's the reason/necessity for using other user's cookies?

Comment: it's from linkedin sales navigator. I need it to scrap some data related to contacts.

Comment: I want to provide my sales with qualified leads